# Getting a database export sent by ftp to another server

Tags: php

OK here is what I am trying to do

Export data from the database, write a csv, then publish to another server.

It will output a csv and download, but I want to write the file on the server, and then publish it from my server to another one.

here goes...

```
function exportMysqlToCsv($table,$filename = 'cmv_sailings.csv')
{
$csv_terminated = "\n";
$csv_separator = ",";
$csv_enclosed = '"';
$csv_escaped = "\\";
$sql_query = "select * from $table";

// Gets the data from the database
$result = mysql_query($sql_query);
$fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);

$schema_insert = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
{
    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
        stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
    $schema_insert .= $l;
    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
} // end for

$out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
$out .= $csv_terminated;

// Format the data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $schema_insert = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
    {
        if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
        {

            if ($csv_enclosed == '')
            {
                $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed .
                str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
            }
        } else
        {
            $schema_insert .= '';
        }

        if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
        {
            $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
        }
    } // end for

    $out .= $schema_insert;
    $out .= $csv_terminated;
} // end while

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
exit;
}
```

// FTP part

```
$connection = ftp_connect("ftp server");
$username = "some user";
$password = "some password";
$login = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) {

    die('oops, connection failed');

} else {

    echo "connection ok <br />";

}

// Ok, I'm connected, log me in...

if(!$login) {

    die('login failed');

} else {

    echo "logged in ok <br />";

}

// Set passive FTP mode

ftp_pasv($connection, true);

// Upload the file

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $filename, $filename, FTP_ASCII);

if(!$upload) { echo "upload failed, doh!"; } else { echo "upload done, thanks!"; }

// We're done, close the connection

ftp_close($connection);
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here ?

thank

Rich :)

Comment: You are missing a question.

Comment: the question is, why doesn't it work ? It stops with 'upload failed'

Comment: Check your server logs for more information.

Comment: The event logs or FTP logs from the server should give you the reason this is failing.  I agree with Bart above that the code looks good, just a bad connection or permission issues that are preventing this from completing successfully.

Comment: Have you tried the FTP code with a cvs file that you know should work? This may help you narrow down the error to either the FTP script or cvs converter file. You could always use phpmyadmin to export a sample CBS file for testing purposes.

Comment: getting this in the error log - PHP Warning:  ftp_put() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given